# The activities involved in this work were: x,y,z

Tags: verbs, past-tense

Talking about a work done in the past, is it correct the sentence?

Comment: What part of the sentence are you wondering about? The tense of the verb "were"?

Comment: @J.Tate  Sounds good if I use the verb were or shall I use had been or another form ?

Comment: What do you want to communicate? Just about any English tense works. You've provided little context from which to offer much assistance.

Comment: For instance: *The activities involved in this work will have been x, y, and z*, *were supposed to have been x, y, and z*, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would use "were" because it is the [third person plural](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/third-person_plural) of the verb "to be" and the subject, "activities" is plural. The past tense of "involved" and "were" matches, so this sentence is fine as is.

Note that you should not use a colon before your list because it disrupts the flow of the sentence. See [here](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/colon.html) for more on this.